# Not able to Show live camera RTSP streaming with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, live-streaming

I'm developing a web application with angular, I need to add a window that shows a live RTSP streaming. After searching I found that can be done with JSMpeg js library. 
In the server side I found this nodejs example

```
Stream = require('node-rtsp-stream')
stream = new Stream({
  name: 'name',
  streamUrl: 'rtsp_url',
  wsPort: 9999,
  ffmpegOptions: { // options ffmpeg flags
    '-stats': '', // an option with no neccessary value uses a blank string
    '-r': 30 // options with required values specify the value after the key
  }
})
```

in the web side I tried as a first step a simple HTML5 example:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <canvas id="canvas"  width="1920" height="1080" style="display: block; width: 40%;"></canvas>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jsmpeg.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9999');
    player = new JSMpeg.Player('ws://localhost:9999', {
      canvas: document.getElementById('canvas'), autoplay: true, audio: false, loop: true
    })  
</script>
</html>
```

This HTML5 page works fine and I got in my web page a live streaming. After that I tried to adapt this HTML code to angular, I installed as first JSMpeg with npm:

```
npm install jsmpeg-player --save
```

I added the canvas tag to the corresponding html file:

```
<canvas #streaming id="canvas"  width="1920" height="1080" style="display: block; width: 40%;"></canvas>
```

Then I tried to adapt the js script to a ts script in the corresponding component like that:

```
@ViewChild('streaming', {static: false}) streamingcanvas: ElementRef; 

constructor( ... ) { }

ngOnInit() {
    ....
    let player = new JSMpeg.Player('ws://localhost:9999', {
        canvas: this.streamingcanvas, autoplay: true, audio: false, loop: true
      })
}
```

the result that I get is that the canvas tag is added but no streaming in my web page an no script errors in the console. I checked the traffic in the browser:

[image]

and seems that the nodejs server receives the websocket request as described in his traces:

[image]

but as I said no streaming in my page:

My question is: what's missing in my ts code? what should I fix?

Comment: What happens when you set static to true in your viewChild?

Comment: @MikeOne: Thank you for your comment, but that doesn't change anything

Comment: @KallelOmar I'm working on a similar application and i'm very interested on how you adapted the js script to angular

Comment: @Q.Rey Almost the same. The only difference is that with js canvas attribute in JSMPEG.Player is gotten with document.getElementById but in typescript canvas value is gootten with ViewChild

Comment: The thing is that I got no error, i opened my websocket on localhost:8081, used ffmpeg to convert .mov format to mjpeg-ts (because mjpeg1video format gave me error), and i only have a black square inside the canvas . I think it's a format error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in ngOnInit `this.streamingcanvas` by `this.streamingcanvas.nativeElement`
it should be like this

```js
ngOnInit() {  
\\ ...  
  let player = new
  JSMpeg.Player('ws://localhost:9999', {
    canvas: this.streamingcanvas.nativeElement, 
    autoplay: true, 
    audio: false, 
    loop: true
  }) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it solves the issue

Comment: @KallelOmar when I tried above solution getting a black square inside the canvas, if possible can you please provide your working solution.

Comment: @srinivasaraoramisetty it's the same in my post question, just replace this.streamingcanvas by this.streamingcanvas.nativeElement

Comment: @KallelOmar I added the same like u said this.streamingcanvas.nativeElement, and @ViewChild('streaming', {static: false}) streamingcanvas: ElementRef;  -> {static:false} changed to {static:true} as the element is calling inside ngOnInit(), can you please help me on it where I am missing.